# Miltitasking and Progress Bar

Tags: java, android

Does Android have multitasking functionality?  If yes, then how can we use it to enable a progress bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Android Supports multitasking functionality , Refer the following link

- [Multitasking the Android Way](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html)
- [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [Create A Custom Progress Bar Using AsyncTask](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/create-a-custom-progress-bar-using-asynctask)
- [ProgressBar running in AsyncTask](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/11/progressbar-running-in-asynctask.html)

Comment: hi....thanks  alot but i want to give time for that progress bar.i.e upto that time it must run.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [slides](http://www.tbray.org/google/LatAm/LatAm-High-Performance-Apps.pdf) from Tim Bray (Google) that not only show how to do a simple task in background but also has an example with progress bar/spin.

Comment: did it help you? Have you seen the example? Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Android very much supports multitasking.

But I am not sure what you want to do with the `ProgressBar`, though

Answer (score 0):

Multitasking is supported.

Go thro this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) for details

Answer (score 0):

Of course, android supports multitasking functionality.
Your question is not very clear, but I think I can say something on this topic. In general, you need to start a thread to archieve this.
I suggest you read this article to learn more about using thread.
[From Google's Android Developer website](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)